# Start Fortnite Windowed?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale, fortnite-save-the-world

I want to be able to start Fortnite windowed before launching so I'm assuming there will be a setting in a local file somewhere that tells the game if it should launch fullscreen or windowed but I can't find it.

How do I launch the game in windowed mode?

---

Note: I do not want answers telling me to change a setting once the game has already launched.

Comment: What is the difference between editing a config file or just doing it in settings? both give the same result.

Comment: @KevinTheGreat To do it in settings I have to launch the game, if I have the game in full screen my remote viewer doesn't show it so I can't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Mine opens in windowed mode by default when launching.

My setting are:

Windowed mode: Windowed

Display Res: 1680x1050 16:10

No changes have been made, this may be a change since the season 4 update as it never used to do this

Answer (score 0):

The Windows operating system supports command-line switches to adjust certain start-up parameters of programs. One way to "force" Fortnite to run in a windowed mode is to create a special shortcut to the games's main executable, then configure that shortcut with the applicable command-line switch.

1. Create a shortcut for Fortnite on your desktop (if you haven't already)
2. Right click the shortcut.
3. Select `properties`
4. In the `Shortcut` tab, in the Target: field, add `-window` or `-w` at the end of the file path.
5. Click `OK` or `Apply` then `OK`

Hope this helps.